# Rails3: generate a URL with params from an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Starting fro this LINE:

```
link_to "delete", [:delete, :backend, @resource]
```

I want to generate a URL like this: /backend/pages/19/delete?locale=en

How can I add params to that array? Something like this:

```
link_to "delete", [:delete, :backend, @resource, :locale => :en]
```

This is the route.rb file:

```
namespace :backend do
    resources :pages do
        member do
            get :delete
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have not shared the contents of `routes.rb`, I can't see how you have defined the route for  `/backend/pages/19/delete`.

In order to pass query string in the link, you could do as shown below:

```
    <%= link_to 'delete', pathname_path(@resource, locale: "en") , method: :delete %>
```

where

Replace `pathname` with the named route for `/backend/pages/19/delete` defined in `routes.rb`.

If you want to include the locale in all the routes, read about [Setting the Locale from the URL Params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params) in Rails Guides.

Comment: You mean to say replace only the `pathname` part as `_path' is required.

Comment: I've upated my route.rb. I don't want to specify the path delete_backend_page_path(@resource), because I've multiple controllers (posts, products, etc) where I want to generate the URL for delete dynamically.